# MDX: efficient way to filter tuples where particular columns are not empty?

Tags: ssas, mdx

Suppose I have an MDX query like this:
`SELECT Measure1, Measure2, Measure3 ON COLUMNS
[Region].[Region].[Region] ON ROWS
FROM TheCube`

If I wanted to exclude rows where ALL THREE measures are empty, I would use SELECT NON EMPTY, which works fast. But I actually need to exclude rows where both Measure1 and Measure2 are empty, even if Measure3 has a value - because in this particular cube Measure3 always has a value, so NON EMPTY has no effect at all.

I could do
`SELECT Measure1, Measure2, Measure3 ON COLUMNS
FILTER ([Region].[Region].[Region], 
       NOT (IsEmpty(Measure1) AND IsEmpty(Measure2)) ON ROWS
FROM TheCube`

and it even works, but it takes forever: an order of magnitude longer than the NON EMPTY query above. In fact, even if I filter by an expression that is always true, like FILTER(..., 1=1), it also takes a lot of time.

Is there a more efficient way to filter out rows where both Measure1 and Measure2 are empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the similar function NonEmpty.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145988.aspx
Here is a good explanation between them: http://thatmsftbiguy.com/nonemptymdx/

Comment: I've seen NonEmpty(). The $1M question is how do I write SELECT with it, i.e. how to add one more column to the result of NonEmpty. Can you come up with an example?

PS. Actually, I did not realize NonEmpty() has a second parameter. That might lead to what I want. But an example is still welcome.

Comment: Alright, more investigation on NonEmpty() it actually does a CROSS JOIN between the first and the second parameters, so passing two sets of measures to it is not going to work.

One might try use NonEmpty() clause with some measures on the rows axis, but this would ignore any filtering and what-not, and therefore is also problematic. Still trying to figure it out...

Comment: NonEmpty() together with the WHERE clause did the trick. As in SELECT Measure1, Measure2, Measure3 ON COLUMNS NonEmpty([Region].[Region].[Region], { [Measure1], [Measure2] }) ON ROWS WHERE -- some filter. If you don't use WHERE, you must be very careful to check what exactly your NonEmpty() runs on.

Answer (score 0):

Just retyping the resulting query in a more readable manner:

`SELECT Measure1, Measure2, Measure3 ON COLUMNS
NonEmpty([Region].[Region].[Region], 
         { [Measure1], [Measure2] }) ON ROWS
WHERE -- some filter`

If you don't use WHERE, you must be very careful to check what exactly your NonEmpty() runs on.